# Display Contrast Ubuntu 14.0.4 x32 on Elitebook2560p

Tags: 14.04, display, hp, color-management

I downloaded icc-profiles and icc-profiles-free from apt-get and this gave me a few more options inside Gnome-Color-Manager / but I still have no option to Calibrate (button is disabled) and all of the profiles are lacking in contrast.

Is there any other display/color management tool I can use to control the contrast of my screen. Or should I try creating my own icc profile to do this?

Also tried `xcalib` but it had no effect.

Thanks!